# can't present modalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, modalviewcontroller

I tried to present a modal view controller on a view did load.

Here's the code:

```
 if (!self.loginNavViewController_){

        AHLoginViewController * loginVC = [[AHLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AHLoginViewController" bundle:nil];

        /*
        AHTestViewController * test  = [[AHTestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AHTestViewController" bundle:nil];
        */

        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC];
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        navController.title = @"Login to Instagram";

        self.loginNavViewController_ = navController;
        [self presentModalViewController:self.loginNavViewController_ animated:YES];


        if (self.loginNavViewController_ == nil){
            NSLog(@"NIL");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"NOT NIL");
        }
```

}

However I don't see a modal view controller being shown. Why??

Comment: Its probably too early to present a model view in viewDidLoad.  Try it in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Comment: @jamihash: +1 for the answer. I think you need to post this as an answer. As this is a correct solution and you were the earliest to point out this fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view controller receives `viewDidLoad` immediately after loading the view and before the view is inserted into a view hierarchy. In other words, it cannot present a modal view controller because its own view is not in any window yet.

Try to do that in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can use in view did load also I am already using this.

```
InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil]; 
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:infoViewController];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:nav.view];
```

you add many model on main view using view did load.

Welcome.

Comment: I don't think this is same as presenting modalView with animated YES. Though it may be same if user doesn't opt to show it being presented and dismissed in animated manner.

Comment: Yes he can use that also But then he should add on present model view like subview than it will be good for him.